# How can I get the tap sound when a user touch a gridlayout?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

How can I get the tap sound when a user touch a gridlayout?

```
<GridLayout row="3" colSpan="2" columns="15*,75*,10*" height="12%" rows="*,*" class="card-large box" (tap)="onTap()">
    <Label text="&#xf17b;" class="fa centered icon-category" col="0" rowspan="2"></Label>
    <Label text="MyText" class="category-name" verticalAlignment="bottom" col="1" row="0"></Label>
    <Label text="numbers" verticalAlignment="top" col="1" row="1"></Label>
    <Label text="&#xf054;" class="fa centered icon-arrow" col="2" rowspan="2"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

UPDATE: I could get the sound by accesing the android native api, here is the code:

let decorView:any = app.android.startActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()
decorView.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK)

but I would like to know why tapping an android layout does not fire the sound effect,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code should work as expected. Here is [a demonstration application](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/tapSound) where the sound effect is triggered when the user taps on the layout ([the layout](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/tapSound) with the [tap event](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/blob/master/stackoverflow/tapSound/app/main-view-model.ts#L13-L18) where the magic is happening)